# How to avoid duplicate code when declaring overridden functions from interface in multiple header files?

Tags: c++, overriding, code-duplication

I have multiple classes inheriting from an interface. The header files of the derived classes are almost equal as each overrides all pure virtual functions:

```
struct IBase {
    virtual void fooA() = 0;
    virtual void fooB() = 0;  
};

struct Derived1 : IBase {
    void fooA() override; 
    void fooB() override;
};

struct Derived2 : IBase {
    void fooA() override; 
    void fooB() override;
};

void Derived1::fooA() {
    // implA1
}
void Derived1::fooB() {
    // implB1
}

void Derived2::fooA() {
    // implA2
}
void Derived2::fooB() {
    // implB2
}
```

Can I somehow avoid copy pasting `void fooA() override; void fooB() override;` for every derived class?

Comment: The point of making a function a pure virtual function is so that you *have to* write your own implementation in each derived class. If you don't want that, don't do it

Comment: This is no code-duplication in my eyes, beacuse the aim of inheritance is to "avoid" code-duplication and only to override functions, that needs to be different

Comment: If you don't declare the overridden functions in the derived classes, how would the compiler know that you actually want to override them?

Comment: Own implementation yes, but the declarations in the headers do not differ anyhow. I could copy paste the entire header file and just change the name of the derived struct. Which seemed strange to me

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude well since it's pure virtual I have to override

Comment: It differs, if you have more derived classes, that do not override the same functions. Maybe your design is "smelly", if you have to override always the same functions

Comment: But, if the code is always the same, you could put it in a macro and set it in every derived class. When you change the base class, you only have to change the macro

Comment: Yes you have to override *somewhere*, but all the compiler sees is the class definition, it will not know if it will be overridden in that class, or in some other class further down the inheritance chain.

Comment: well ok but I don't think it's smelly design to have an interface where instantiable classes derive from

Comment: @JonasHerzog inheritance isn't always a good solution. I don't know your use-case, and it could be, that inheritance is good. But saying, "I use inheritance, this has to to be good", would not always be true

Comment: Lets say you have a system that should emulate animal behavior. You could start out with simple behaviors (like e.g. `move`) as abstract classes that defines the behavior (but doesn't implement them). Then you could add more specialized variants of that behavior (e.g. `walk` and `trott`), or combine multiple behaviors, until you get down to a single specific animal which implements the behavior. The abstract functions then need to be passed to the concrete animal structure which implement them. Just because you can't currently see a use-case doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Comment: I like to think that "code-duplication" has two meanings:

**Literal)** You copy-paste code, so the code is duplicated since the exact sequence of characters exist twice, or

**Logical)** If find a single bug, you have to fix that bug in two or more places within your code base instead of only one place.

I think that logical code-duplications are smelly and literal code-duplications are unfortunate but necessary.

Comment: A bit of source code text duplication is something you have to deal with in C and C++, especially between headers and source files, but it shouldn't have a negative effect on the binary itself. Languages with different (often newer)  syntax avoid some such duplication, especially dynamically typed ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to avoid copy pasting `void fooA() override; void fooB() override;` for every derived class, under the assumption that their implementations are indeed different (as indicated by your comment `// implA1` and `// implA2`), *without resorting to macros*.

**NOTE:** If the implementations of `Derived1::fooA` and `Derived2::fooA` are identical, then it is possible to avoid the duplication.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a common block of code that *all* derived classes *always* need to call before, after or as part of their own specialization (or even just *usually*), then you could provide that as an implementation for the pure virtual in the base class (yes, pure virtual *can* have an implementation). Then everyone still has to implement the function (still pure), but they can call the base class function for the common stuff.